# Java ArrayList<T> .convertall

Tags: java, arraylist

Does something like c# .convertall in Java exist?

Like

```
ArrayList<MyCalss> list = new ArrayList<MyClass>();
list.convertall(new Converter(...));
```

Comment: Instead of asking for conversion, explain what you want exactly. In short, sorry I don't know C#.

Answer (score 4):

Depending on what exactly you mean by a converter, in Java 8 something like this could work:

```
ArrayList<MyClass> list = new ArrayList<MyClass>(someObjectsToFillTheList);
List<OtherClass> list2 = list.stream()
    .map(s -> new OtherClass(s)).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

In this case, the *conversion* is done by the constructor of `OtherClass`.

Comment: ...or just `.map(OtherClass::new)`.

Answer (score 0):

For Java 8, see jpmath's answer. For lower versions, you either have to take the long walk and write a loop that iterates through your collection and adds the converted result to another list or you can have a look at the [Guava library](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/FunctionalExplained).

As there are no lambdas/closures in Java <8, you can use an anonymous function within the [Lists#transform()-method](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Lists.html#transform(java.util.List,%20com.google.common.base.Function)).